Managing Flyway while connectings multiple db's SpringBoot
I am trying to connect to db's from one service Uisng ENTITY MANAGER .  and I am writing flyway's for both the db's .
But it excutes which datascource marked as primary .and its not allowing to create file with same migration number . getting duplicy error.
Schema looks like this
to ignore duplicy error if we name them in the serial way second db starting with 5 . all the tables are created in the single DB which is marked as primary .
my yml looks like : hikari:
datasource:
loan:
jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
username:
driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
password:
locations: classpath:/db/migration/db1
bureau:
jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
username:
driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
password:
locations: classpath:db/migration/db2
I tried using postconstruct method in the config class still gtwting the duplicy error.
@PostConstruct
public void bureauMigration(@Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource dataSource){
    Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .locations(locations)
            .load()
            .migrate();
}

